# how to set Listview item non clickable based on content in it in android

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am developing an android application,in which I am using ListView with custom adapter and I want to set clickable and non clickable items in ListView base on thier content.I search for the same but everywhere the answer was to used below method.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

But its not what I want to achieved.So anybody has any idea how to achieved this?

here is my custom adapter code

```
public class History_List_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<User_History_List> historyList;
TextView time,cost,ride_time,bike_number,source_location,destination_location;
User_History_List userHistoryList;
ImageView live_status;

public Bicycle_History_List_Adapter(Activity activity, List<User_History_List> lists) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.historyList = lists;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return historyList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return historyList.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(inflater == null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_list,null);
    }
    time = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_history_time);
    bike_number = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_history_bike_number);
    cost = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_history_rental);
    ride_time = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_history_ride_time);
    source_location = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_history_source_address);
    destination_location = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_history_destination_address);
    live_status = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ride_status);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "font/Catamaran_Regular.ttf");
    time.setTypeface(tf);
    bike_number.setTypeface(tf);
    cost.setTypeface(tf);
    ride_time.setTypeface(tf);
    source_location.setTypeface(tf);
    destination_location.setTypeface(tf);

    userHistoryList = historyList.get(position);

    time.setText(getDate_Time(userHistoryList.getPickup_time()));
    bike_number.setText(userHistoryList.getBike_number());
    source_location.setText(userHistoryList.getSourse_address());
    destination_location.setText(userHistoryList.getDestination_address());
    if(userHistoryList.getIs_live().equals("RIDING")){
        cost.setText("Live");
        ride_time.setText(getride_time(userHistoryList.getPickup_time()));
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        live_status.startAnimation(animation);
        convertView.setEnabled(false);
    }else if(userHistoryList.getIs_live().equals("OUTSTANDING")){
        cost.setText("Live");
        ride_time.setText(getride_time(userHistoryList.getPickup_time()));
        live_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_oustanding_24px);
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        live_status.startAnimation(animation);
        convertView.setEnabled(false);
    }else {
        cost.setText("₹"+userHistoryList.getCost()+"/-");
        ride_time.setText(gettime(userHistoryList.getRide_time()));
        live_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_live_status_24px);
        convertView.setEnabled(true);
    }


    return convertView ;
}

public String getDate_Time(Long milisecond){
    Date current_date = new Date(milisecond);

    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("E,dd MMM yy h:mm a");

    return dateformat.format(current_date);
}

public String getride_time(Long milisecond){
    Date booking_date = new Date(milisecond);
    Date current_date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    return gettime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(current_date.getTime() - booking_date.getTime()));
}


public String gettime(Long min){
    String time;
    int hr = (int) (min/60);
    int minutes = (int)(min%60);
    if(hr >0) {
        time = hr + "hr " + minutes + "min";

    }else {
        time = minutes + "min";
    }
    return time ;
}
}
```

Comment: So what do you want to do?

Comment: In your click listener, do action after checking  the condition for a content

Comment: @Eselfar I want to check the content of the listview item and on that condition want to set the clickable function.

Comment: @JyotiJK but how can i check the content of the item of ListView?

Comment: What are you doing can you show your adapter of the listview, I change the code according to your requirement.

Comment: and you also do set your row with set enable to true or false according to your conditions but used the view-holder

Comment: @Nikhilpatil post your adapter and say which type of item should not be clickable

Comment: @Arjunsaini please check out my adapter code. In that there is status field which content 2 values RIDING,OUTSTANDING when status is RIDING then i have to disable the click event

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo in proper way, but i am not getting any idea how can I achieved this. Can you tell me the proper way?

Comment: @Nikhilpatil I will post my answer.

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo it would be great for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below method to make view non clickable as per your condition

yourView.setEnabled(false);

In activity

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
      if(!userHistoryList.get(position).getIs_live().equals("RIDING")&&!userHistoryList.get(position).getIs_live().equals("OUTSTANDING")){

    //do something for a valid click
}

});
```

Comment: In custom adapter i have to set view enable false or true?

Comment: I tried your answer but still it clicking. Can you please check the code of my adapter and tell me where should i put  View.setEnabled(false);

Comment: sure, i can see you are not handling the clicks in adapter, so i would suggest to achieve that you will have to keep an if else condition in your onItemClickListner of your Listview object in the activity,
i can guide you more if you can show how the clicks are handled in activity

Comment: Now check I added the convertView.setEnabled(false); according to the condition.

Comment: yes, but this may not work as the clicks are handled in your situation by the Listview itself, so i think you will have to handle it in listview item click listener, i will add it to my ans, as i cant post code properly in comments

Comment: But in onItemClickListner how can i check the condition,because in that method i am not able to check the content of the listview item

Comment: you must be providing List<User_History_List> lists in the adapter in the activity right?, use that its the same data the list is populated with, so it should work

Comment: Yes i got it,so i have to set convertView.setEnabled(false); in onItemClickListner right?

Comment: no in your case you dont need to do enable disable thing, just keep this condition in your item click listner in your activity, as i have added in my answer and you are good to go, also please accept my ans if it helped

Comment: glad to help :)